# How to declare a variable outside the return statement and switch variables when the user clicks on the link in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm relatively new to ReactJS and I'm trying to build a schedule for my school club. [So this is a picture of my website.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TsEc.png)

What I want to do is be able to change the schedule on clicking any of the other days on the schedule calendar. So if I were to click Saturday, it would be 'active' so it would turn blue, and then the events of that day would show. And the same for Sunday. I don't know how to implement that. I essentially need to declare a variable outside the return statement and switch variables when the user clicks on the link.

```
const schedule = () => {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <div className='schedule-page'>
                <Navbar />
                <MobileNavBar />
                <div className='schedule-map'>
                    <div className='sche-side'>
                        <div className='timer'>
                            <div className='timer-header'>
                                <h1>Timer</h1>
                            </div>
                            <div className='timer-second-row'>
                                <div className='next-event'>
                                    <h2>New Event</h2>  
                                </div>
                                <div className='start-time'>
                                    <h2>Start Time</h2>
                                </div>
                                <div className='countdown'>
                                    <h2>Countdown</h2>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <h1>Schedule</h1>
                        <div className='sche-date'>
                            <div className='fri-day'>
                                <div className='day active'>Fri. Feb, 21</div>
                            </div>
                            <div className='first-day'>
                                <div className='day'>Sat. Feb, 22</div>
                            </div>
                            <div className='second-day'>
                                <div className='day'>Sun. Feb, 23</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className='events'>
                            <ul className='event-ul'>
                                <li className='event event-active'>
                                    <span className='time'>4:00PM</span>
                                    <span className='todo'>Check-In</span>
                                    <span className='detail'>Be sure to check your email and fill out the hacker check-in form, then hop onto our Hopin and Discord!</span>
                                </li>
                                <li className='event'>
                                    <span className='time'>6:00PM</span>
                                    <span className='todo'>Opening Ceremony</span>
                                    <span className='detail'>Come join the opening ceremony for SacHacks 2021 to hear from our amazing sponsors and learn more about our hackathon!</span>
                                </li>
                                <li className='event'>
                                    <span className='time'>6:15PM</span>
                                    <span className='todo'>IBM Keynote Workshop</span>
                                    <span className='detail'>Come learn more about IBM Z</span>
                                </li>
                                <li className='event'>
                                    <span className='time'>7:00PM</span>
                                    <span className='todo'>Hacking Starts + Team Mixer</span>
                                    <span className='detail'>Don’t have a team? No worries! Meet and team up with other hackers to launch your ideas at SacHacks 2021!</span>
                                </li>
                                <li className='event'>
                                    <span className='time'>7:30PM</span>
                                    <span className='todo'>Datathon for Social Good: ML on Z</span>
                                    <span className='detail'>Learn about machine learning on Z from IBM engineers and last year’s IBM Z winners!</span>
                                </li>
                                <li className='event'>
                                    <span className='time'>9:10PM</span>
                                    <span className='todo'>Intro to UI/UX</span>
                                    <span className='detail'>Want to make your project stand out? Learn more about UI/UX Design in this interactive workshop hosted by Grace from Design Buddies!</span>
                                </li>
                                <li className='event'>
                                    <span className='time'>10:10PM</span>
                                    <span className='todo'>Exploding Designer's Block</span>
                                    <span className='detail'>Come learn more about game design in our Exploding Designer’s Block workshop, hosted by Dan, Lead Designer at EA!</span>
                                </li>
                                <li className='event'>
                                    <span className='time'>11:30PM</span>
                                    <span className='todo'>Intro to Web Dev HTML/CSS</span>
                                    <span className='detail'>No experience with Web Development? Come build a website with HTML and CSS!</span>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <Copyright />
        </React.Fragment>
    );
};

export default schedule;
```

This is my code for the current website. If you want I can show the CSS file too. Would appreciate it if someone could help me out!

Comment: This is a really basic question. You should make yourself familiar with the `useState` hook. General outline of how you could do it: Extract each days markup into a dedicated component and then hold the currently active day in react state and decide depending on the current state value which component to render. Add handlers to the tabs to switch the state when someone clicks it.

Comment: its basic question, I can see here you didn't complete any reactJS course yet, you need to take some course it's really important and learn how to use react hooks

Comment: Okay so I actually did use the ```useState``` hook but whenever I call it, I get ```Line 22:33:  React Hook "useState" is called in function "schedule" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function react-hooks/rules-of-hooks```

Answer (score 0):

Use useState hooks

```
const schedule = () => {
const [active,setActive]=useState("");
.....
}
```

u can change the value of active by

```
setActive("Saturday")
```

This causes the component to rerender.
State is a very basic and the most commonly used concept in react, so I suggest you make yourself familiar with it.

Comment: So I did that and I got an error of 
```Line 22:33:  React Hook "useState" is called in function "schedule" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function react-hooks/rules-of-hooks ```

Comment: name the component Schedule instead of schedule, React fails to identify schedule as  a component as its all in lower case. Always start a components name with caps